# I am getting this error "MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: null }"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, server

I am a student and currently I'm making a login authentication API using Node, Express and MongoDB.  I want to be able to sign up with multiple users however, whenever I try to add another user it doesn't let me. How can I solve it? I looked through almost every threads in this website related to my question but it still doesn't answer it. Now, I am truly lost. Below is my code and this is the exact error I get: [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBp4A.png)

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://marithe:pMn6xAGMmbIcfQMI@express-crud.lsr5iia.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

const User = mongoose.model('User', {
  username: String,
  password: String,
});

const ResetToken = mongoose.model('ResetToken', {
  username: String,
  token: String,
});

app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    const existingUser = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Username already registered' });
    }

    const user = new User({ username, password });
    await user.save();

    res.status(201).json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error registering user' });
  }
});

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }

    if (user.password !== password) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Incorrect password' });
    }

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login successful' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Login failed' });
  }
});

app.post('/forgot-password', async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.body;
  const user = await User.findOne({ username });

  if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
  }
  
  const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');

  const resetTokenDoc = new ResetToken({ username, token: resetToken });
  await resetTokenDoc.save();

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Reset token sent', resetToken });
});

app.post('/reset-password', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, token, newPassword } = req.body;

  const storedTokenDoc = await ResetToken.findOne({ username, token });

  if (!storedTokenDoc) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Invalid reset token' });
  }

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ username });
    user.password = newPassword;
    await user.save();
    
    await ResetToken.deleteOne({ username, token });

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Password reset successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Password reset failed' });
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a unique index on the `email` key, and there's already another entry in the database with `email` set to `null`.

To solve this, you either need to remove the unique index, or add validation to your application to check if an email already exists before trying to save the user.

It however looks like you don't need the email field, so I recommend you remove it entirely.

To find the name of the index, connect to the database, e.g.

```
➜ mongosh --port 27017
Current Mongosh Log ID:  123a4bc5d67891011ef1213g
Connecting to:    mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/
For mongosh info see: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/
test>
```

Use this command to list the indexes:

```
db.collection.getIndexes()
```

And to drop it,

```
db.collection.dropIndex(indexName)
```

You can find more information about this on the [MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/).